# Are oxides of sulphur and carbon adsorbed into limestone/marble?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, materials, surface-chemistry

Oxides of sulphur and carbon are commonly present in the atmostphere in areas close to industries, can such oxides get adsorbed into the surface of limestone and marble and cause discolouration and corrosion ?

If yes, then what amount of such oxides will get adsorbed into the surface over time as the amount of avalible surface for adsorption varys for every material.

Comment: Study the concept of acid rain. There is not adsorption but these oxides react with moisture in the air and form acids. Yes, limestone gets damaged.

Comment: $|ce{CO}$, $\ce{CO2}$ or $\ce{SO2}$  are not absorbed on limestone or marble. But if $\ce{CO2}$ or $\ce{SO2}$ is dissolved in water, their solutions can react with marble or limestone, but these reactions are rather slow, according to $\ce{CaCO3 + CO2 + H2O -> Ca^{2+} + 2 HCO3^-}$ or $\ce{CaCO3 + SO2 + H2O -> Ca^{2+} + HCO3^- + HSO3^-}$.